# Converting parent-child relations into a tree with attributes

Tags: r, tree, parent-child

This is probably basic, but I cannot find out how to do this using data.tree. My data has the following structure:

```
data <- data.frame(ParentFolderID = c("a", "b", "b", "e"), 
               FolderID = c("b", "d", "e", "f"), 
               FolderName = c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4"), 
               Values1 = c(1:4),
               Values2 = c(2,1,4,2),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I need to create a tree with this data, such that the nodes contain the information: FolderName, Value1 and Value2. Using the function **FromDataFrameNetwork** from **data.tree** I can make this happen.

```
FromDataFrameNetwork(test)
          levelName
1 a            
2  °--b        
3      ¦--d    
4      °--e    
5          °--f
```

I can, however, not figure out how to add the other information to the tree. Do you have any suggestions? The documentation does not explain this well unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparantly you just add a vector with the columns that you want to include.

```
tree <- FromDataFrameNetwork(data, c("FolderName", "Values1", "Values2"))

> print(tree, "FolderName", "Values2", "Values1")
      levelName FolderName Values2 Values1
1 a                             NA      NA
2  °--b                 N1       2       1
3      ¦--d             N2       1       2
4      °--e             N3       4       3
5          °--f         N4       2       4
```

Comment: Your FolderNames is a factor. Use stringsAsFactors = false when creating the data.frame, and your code will work.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about that. I should have learned by now :)